# Asociar un conjunto de tablas mediante linq

Tags: c#

Hola estoy intentando referenciar un conjunto de tablas para poder usar los datos de algunos registros. Para esto empleó lo siguiente:

```
    void asociarcamposforms() {
                var idpedido = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["idpedido"]);

                var queryObtenerdtpedido = db.detalle_pedido.Where(dt => dt.id_pedido == idpedido);
                var pedido = queryObtenerdtpedido.FirstOrDefault();

                var idarticulo = pedido.articuloid;

                var queryObtenerArticulo = db.articuloes.Where(p => p.articuloid == idarticulo);
                var articulos = queryObtenerArticulo.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

funciona perfectamente, pero me gustaría conocer si hay alguna forma de reducir todo ese procedimiento que realizo. Esto es solo un fragmento de codigo los demas procesos son condiciones y metodos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haciendo Join con las tablas, así sólo se hace una consulta en lugar de dos.

```
void asociarcamposforms()
{
    var idpedido = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["idpedido"]);

    var query = from p in db.detalle_pedido
                join a in db.articuloes on p.articuloid equals a.articuloid
                where p.id_pedido == idpedido
                select a;

    var articulos = query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```